# Input text value not getting changed after deletion

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have question on HTML and Jquery.

Here is my script below:

```
var currentTemplate = 0;

$(document).ready(function(){
$("#emailTempTd"+currentTemplate).css("border", "1px solid");       

$("a[name='emailTemp']").click(function(){
        var relId = $(this).attr("rel");

        if(currentTemplate != relId){
            $("#emailTemplate").attr("value", $(this).html());
            $("#emailTemplateId").attr("value", relId);

            $("#emailTempTd"+currentTemplate).css("border", "");
            $("#emailTempTd"+relId).css("border", "1px solid");
            currentTemplate = relId;
        }// end if
    });

});
```

You can also see the complete HTML and script [here.](https://jsfiddle.net/have_full/1oatnvhr/14/)

Here are my expectations:

- Every time user clicks blank/blank2/blank3, it should automatically
  fill Template Name and Template Id (hidden) fields.
- User can modify Template Name manually. I was able to make jquery for
  those and it was running fine, until I reach point no 2.

The problem occur when the user follows the following step:

1. Click on blank2/blank3. (Then template name and template id being
   filled automatically)
2. User deletes or modifies template name field.
3. User clicks other option (blank/blank1/blank2).

The template name and template ID value aren't changed.

But if you use firebug or developer tools for chrome, their values are changed. However the appearance is not changed. It got stuck on what the customer input was.

I used mozilla version 50.0.2 and chrome version 55.0.2883.87

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace this

```
$("#emailTemplate").attr("value", $(this).html());
$("#emailTemplateId").attr("value", relId);
```

with this one

```
$("#emailTemplate").val($(this).html());
$("#emailTemplateId").val(relId);
```

Comment: I just realise that there's a major different between attr() and val().
thanks mate